# Why is no root pass needed to access MariaDB after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've recently upgraded a system from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB) and noticed root can get in without a password eg:`mysql -u root` is empty.

Tried setting a new pass via mysql with `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('supersekrit') WHERE User = 'root';` however this didn't disable the empty password. Also tried running `mysql_secure_installation` to no avail.

Found a [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385202/mariadb-accepts-any-password) about setting the `plugin` field in the user row to 'NULL'. I did that, but now root cannot login at all.

I followed the link to percona in the post, which states *the correct way to do this is to run the following:* `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';`. This results in and error message -> `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax...`

Not quite sure what the correct way is to fix this. any ideas?

**UPDATE**: after setting the password for the root mysql account, Ubuntu 16.04 cron daemon is now throwing errors during logrotate. Looks like this issue is a rabbit hole.  I've emptied the root password for now until I can figure out what's borked with logrotate. Yeesh.

```
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you can access as the root user is likely due to the fact that [UNIX domain socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) is enabled. Given that the [`ALTER USER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/) command failed, you are likely running a pre-10.2 MariaDB.

You can create a replacement user with the same grants as `root` by copying the grants in `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'`:

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For example, if I want to have my user named as  `backup-root` with the password set to `password`, I would execute the following:

```
CREATE USER 'backup-root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'backup-root'@'localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: the `unix_socket` plugin was the reason root had an empty password. That added some confusion to the fact that two of the 16.04 VMs I was provisioning had different SQL stacks installed -- one Mysql, the other MariaDB. These two bundles are now  different enogh that password handling is completely different between the two. for MariaDB: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');` for Mysql: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'supersekrits';`. I like your idea about creating a `backup-root` user however. Would also be a good fix.